# Select the unique records from duplicates record using group by

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates

I have a table with duplicate records say example multiple records with same account number. like this

[image: snippet of duplicate records]

Now I want to select only those records id which satisfies below condition priority wise:

1. Select the account number for which the prim_cust is X
2. If X is null than select account number which is having dept_id not null.
3. Both null than we should select the min(id).

Here we will have to group the account number and perform the above conditions.
I just want single record with unique account number with above conditions satisfied.

The condition should follow the priority

[image: final output]

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @anonymous13b . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a prioritization query, where you want one row per `acct_nbr` subject to your various rules.

For this type of problem, `row_number()` is quite handy:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by acct_nbr
                                order by (case when prim_cust = 'X' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case when dept_id is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                         id
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```